# How to solve Non-Maximum Suppression from Image

Tags: python, object, detection

[image: 1]

> This is the bank sheet image from where I want to extract the data column wise. I am using Matterport git for this task and as you can see that there are multiple mask and bounding boxes on same columns. Please guide me how can remove masks and bounding boxes with lowest confidence score. And one more thing how can I over come overlapping issue.